# Nodejs PDF file did not look like the html file after conversion

Tags: html, node.js, express, ejs

hello i  wrote an ejs file and i try to convert it to pdf via node js but the probleme is that the pdf file didnot look like the html page i tryed this conversion online and i found good result 
this is my methode

```
router.get("/uknow", (req, res) => {

 //console.log(data[1].test);

  //console.log(posts);
  ejs.renderFile(path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'views', 'resultat.ejs'), {}, function(err, str) {
    if (err) return res.send(err);
    var options = {
      format: "A4",
      orientation: "portrait",

    };
    // str now contains your rendered html
    pdf.create(str,options).toFile("report.pdf", function(err, data) {
      if (err) return res.send(err);

      res.send('Ok');
      });    
    });
  });
```

[image]
this is the html look

[image]
and this is the pdf loook
[image]
and this is how it looks after the online conversion
i need some helps and thank you

Comment: "... did not look like .." - how is it different exactly? What is the exact problem?

Comment: i will post two image

Comment: it's ok i add some screen shot

Comment: All the same elements are present in both. This could just be due to how the css is written up. Remember, you've got the pdf in portrait, but the html is neither in portrait nor landscape but some much larger page size.

Comment: i will add the result of online conversion and you will understand what i mean

Comment: i add a new screenshot try to take a look on it